# partial view opening on new page instead jQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor

I have an ActionLink in my razor view

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.sifra_pozicije, "UnosuProjekat", "Projekti", new { pos = item.sifra_pozicije.ToString() }, new {  @class = "openDialog" })
```

generating HTML code `<a href="/Projekti/UnosuProjekat?pos=VSG010001" class="openDialog">VSG010001</a>`

and javascript that should open jQuery UI dialog with partial view

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $(".openDialog").on("click", ".openDialog", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');

        $("#dialog-edit").dialog({
            title: 'Add Student',
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 355,
            width: 400,
            show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                alert("test");
                //$(this).load("/Projekti/UnosuProjekat");
            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        });

        $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});
```

there is also `return PartialView("_prj", pv.projekat);` in my controller.

I'm loading following scripts in _Layout page:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/globalize/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/globalize/cultures/globalize.culture.sr-Latn.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

but instead of jquery dialog, my partial view opens in full page browser window.

Can someone help me how to actually do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `on` binding is incorrect:

```
$(".openDialog").on("click", ".openDialog", function(e) {... }
```

The second `.openDialog` selector is meant to limit the binding scope to the **descendants** of the first selector. But you don't have an element matching '.openDialog' that is also a descendant of another element that matches '.openDialog'.

Hence your `click` event isn't bound to your `<a>` and the default event is raised - loading another page.

Try this instead:

```
$(".openDialog").on("click", function(e) {... }
```

See [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: there is one error in console, but i think it's not related to this... it's something about globalize.js, and that is gone when i changed order of validate and globalize scripts...